# When using cfpLoadingBar inside '$viewContentLoaded' and '$stateChangeStart' I get Infinite $digest Loop

Tags: angularjs

The following code will cause Infinite $digest Loop:

```
$scope.$on '$viewContentLoaded', ->
    cfpLoadingBar.complete()

$scope.$on '$stateChangeStart', ->
    cfpLoadingBar.start()
```

What is the proper way to trigger start and complete functions on a state change and success?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's better to use cfp.loadingBarInterceptor

No need to worry about starting and stopping manually!

For anyone that might be struggling, read the docs and raise issues on git, they're pretty snappy with replies:

https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar#how-it-works